# PostgreSQL: INSERT INTO syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm following an older tutorial learning Postgres, so it's possible maybe something has changed since it was published. In the tutorial (using psql) I create a table then do some `insert` statements. Here is the tutorial and corresponding `psql` commands that cause error:

http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/11/create-table-and-constraints.html

```
create table people(
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar NOT NULL
);
insert into people(0,'Steve Jobs');
insert into people(1,'Mike Markkula');
insert into people(2,'Mike Scott');
insert into people(3,'John Sculley');
insert into people(4,'Michael Spindler');
insert into people(5,'Gil Amelio');
insert into people(6,'Mike Scott');
```

I get this error for each insert statement:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "0"
LINE 1: insert into people(0,'Steve Jobs');
                           ^
```

I've tried copy pasting, capitalizing the sql commands (ie `INSERT`), running the command from shell outside of `psql`, adding spaces, using `"` instead of `'` quotes... All result in the same errors. Has something changed or am I possibly doing something wrong?

Comment: You are missing the `values` keyword: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html That tutorial is plain wrong

Comment: Yep that was it. I thought I had tried that as well, maybe I did `value` instead of `values`. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the missing `values` (as noted in a comment).

I want to make some suggestions.  First, whenever you use `insert`, you should always list the columns.  This is especially important if you are learning the language -- you should be learning good habits.

Second, you don't need multiple `inserts`.  A shorter way to insert multiple rows is:

```
insert into people (id, name)
    values (0,'Steve Jobs'),
           (1,'Mike Markkula'),
           (2,'Mike Scott'),
           (3,'John Sculley'),
           (4,'Michael Spindler'),
           (5,'Gil Amelio'),
           (6,'Mike Scott');
```

And you should learn about `serial`.  A more common way to write this code would be:

```
create table people (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar NOT NULL
);

insert into people (name)
    values ('Steve Jobs'),
           ('Mike Markkula'),
           ('Mike Scott'),
           ('John Sculley'),
           ('Michael Spindler'),
           ('Gil Amelio'),
           ('Mike Scott');
```

The `id` is assigned automatically by the database (starting at `1` rather than `0`).

I should add:  I am personally uncomfortable with having `varchar` without a length.  This is perfectly fine in Postgres, but some databases would interpret it as `varchar(1)`.